# Expectation of a maximum function (Option pricing)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, expected-value

I have a question regarding expectation of a maximum function.

How do I solve;

$E[\max(S(T)-K, 0)]$

where $K$ is a constant and $S(T)$ is defined as,

$S(T)=S(t)e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)+\sigma(W(T)-W(t))}$

$W$ is a brownian motion.

Comment: $S(T)$ is log-normally distributed with mean $S_0e^{rT}$, variance $S_0^2 e^{2 \mu T}(e^{\sigma^2 T}-1)$

Next, integrate $S(T)-K$ times the density of the log-normal distribution over the range $S(T)\geq K$ to find your answer.

Comment: (That's the same as lognormal with parameters $(r \ln S_0 -\frac{\sigma^2 T}{2}, \sigma^2 T)$)